# Which bit ubuntu os for me?

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows xp sp3 and Kingston 2gb ram module. I don't know much difference between 32 bit os of ubuntu and the 64bit one. Which one should i download?

Comment: For 2Gb RAM it is good to use 32 bit

Comment: Why not the 64bit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue comes down to two things:

**Is your system equipped with a 64-bit processor?  You can usually accomplish this by finding out the specs for the machine.**

1. If it's not a 64-bit processor, then you can't use a 64-bit operating system.
2. If it IS a 64-bit processor, you can install either the 32-bit or 64-bit operating system.  But note that a 32-bit operating system can't ever use more than 4 gb of RAM.  If you ever decide to increase your RAM, the 32-bit operating system will have this limitation, but the 64-bit operating system will not.